# Node.js Lambda functions with container images does not work

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, docker, aws-lambda

I want to try Lambda's nodejs Container,
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-image.html
I've tried doing exactly as described in but it doesn't work

I tried the following according to the sample's curl command

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9000/2015-03-31/functions/function/invocations" -d '{}'
```

I get an error.

```
{
"errorType":"SyntaxError",
"errorMessage":"Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 0",
"trace":[
  "SyntaxError: Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 0"," at 
     JSON.parse (<anonymous >)"," at Runtime.handleOnceNonStreaming 
     (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1086:42)"
 ]
}
```

Sample Code is

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify('Hello from Lambda!'),
    };
    return response;
};
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Could you add some more information? Where are you trying to use that and how did you made configuration? Are you trying to use that locally or deploying to the cloud? Are you creating that lambda via AWS Console?

Comment: Thank you for the answer .I created Dockerfile  below and build and  run it on my Docker DeskTop on  Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

No error occurred when executing the following curl command on Windows 10.

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9000/2015-03-31/functions/function/invocations" -d "{}"
```